# Cookie Rejected For Rest API call

Tags: java, rest, http, salesforce

After one year of working, the java code is suddenly rising the below error

> Feb 02, 2017 6:28:39 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
>   processCookieHeaders WARNING: Cookie rejected: "$Version=0;
>   BrowserId=Mx-kTzLhTUm29MoIKmS6ag; $Path=/; $Domain=.salesforce.com".
>   Domain attribute ".salesforce.com" violates RFC 2109: host minus
>   domain may not contain any dots

I am not a java developer to solve this issue. I don't have any idea about this error.

My code sameple where am using httpclient

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();   
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(HttpClientParams.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(HttpClientParams.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2965);
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(tokenUrl);
post.addParameter("grant_type", grant_type);
post.addParameter("client_id", client_id);
post.addParameter("client_secret", client_secret);
post.addParameter("username", username);
post.addParameter("password", password);

httpclient.executeMethod(post);
```

What do I need to solve this issue. Any help is appreciable. Thanks!!!

**Edit**

Packages used in the class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
```

Comment: Do you know what version of HTTP Client you are using?  Did auth stop working or are you just seeing this new warning?

Comment: @JamesWard - Am just seeing this new error. And it is not yet solved

Comment: That looks like just a warning so it shouldn't really cause any problems.  But if you want to resolve it I think the best option is to update to the latest version of httpclient.  Here is a little project that has the latest: https://github.com/jamesward/salesforce-rest-starter

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I have solved.

You must put this one:

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(HttpClientParams.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

instead of:

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(HttpClientParams.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2965);
```

**BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY** is compatible with the common cookie management practices, on the other hand, **RFC2109** compliant is by default.

Please accept my advice :)